# CSS Selector first of children, NOT siblings

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select only the first instance of an element without the selector triggering for any children? Children as in descendants, not siblings.

In example `ul:first-of-type` would select the first unordered list though any submenus (`ul ul`, `ul li ul` and `ul ul ul ul ul`) would *also* be selected. I only want to select the first instance of a `ul` element within `#menu`.

I *could* do the following though it's pointlessly convoluted.

```
#menu ul:not(ul ul):not(ul ul ul):not(ul ul ul ul) {property: value;}
```

No, I also can not do `#menu > ul` as the number of elements between `#menu` and `ul` varies.

```
<nav id="menu">/* display: flex; justify-content: space-between; */
<div>
<ul>/* Primary, select THIS ul (no > in selector!) */
 <li>Menu</li>
 <li>Menu</li>
 <li>Menu
 <ul>/* Secondary menu. */
 <li>Menu</li>
 <li>Menu
  <ul>/* Tertiary menu. */
  <li>Menu</li>
  <li>Menu</li>
  <li>Menu</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Menu</li>
 </ul> 
 </li>
 <li>Menu</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
/* Auxiliary menu items on right side of menu bar, may contain ul (do not select these either). */
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need two selectors. Select the first one + the other (`ul`) and then select the other (`ul ul`)

Comment: as a side note if we can use complex selector inside not() you will only need to do `#menu ul:not(ul ul)` since space mean any descendant

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh, valid point! I'm going to try that! :D

Comment: @TemaniAfif Um, `#menu ul:not(ul ul)` doesn't select *any* `ul` elements, Waterfox/Chrome. Having a serious WTH moment here...

Comment: This is why we use classes.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've edited in some HTML and I'm going through lists of selectors currently. I'm not sure what your first comment suggests. My goal is to make the first `ul {height: 100%}` without effecting the others...I could apply `height: auto` in a secondary selector I suppose though still a bit messy.

Comment: this is your only way actually, to apply height:auto in the secondary selector. I don't there is a *one-selector* way (until not() will evolve)

Comment: `#menu ul:not(ul ul)` this selector is not valid actually, I simply supposed that if it was valid you only need it and not the long one you made

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for your help! I've posted an answer with some clarifications. Let's hope that the CSS editors decide to add descendant support for selectors at some point in the near future. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least at the time of this post and having gone through some extensive lists of selectors it at least *appears* that all *type* selectors are based on siblings, not descendants. So in order to make the first `ul` element in the menu have `height: 100%` without effecting secondary and tertiary `ul` elements I added a second selector.

```
#menu ul, #menu ul > li, #menu ul > li > a {align-items: center; display: flex; height: 100%;}
#menu ul ul {height: initial;}
```

This in part allows me to have drop down menus *always* horizontally centered beneath primary menus in combination with CSS variables for the total height of the primary header (in which the menu is a descendant of).

Because I work on a platform I can *not* add CSS classes as I please thus I *must* utilize what selectors are available.

Hopefully in the future CSS selectors will continue to expand to include descendant selectors in addition to the sibling selectors.

Comment: it's on the road: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation (note the : *In Selectors Level 3, only a single simple selector was allowed as the argument to :not().*)